# NGUI против стандартного GUI Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d, gui

Есть два вопроса по поводу использования GUI в Unity3d. Недавно попробовал использовать NGUI, вместо стандартного GUI Unity. Но я никак не могу понять, как взаимодействовать через код с элементами сцены. Накидал пару кнопок и панель. Панель находится вне зоны видимости. При нажатии на кнопку, панель должна выезжать на центр камеры.

Копался в документации, но так и не понял, как все это использовать. Буду благодарен, если покажете или дадите ссылку, где это описано.

В силу того, что сейчас для меня NGUI, как темный лес, я задумался, а может все-таки использовать стандартную обертку?

По сути, на сервер будут отсылаться лишь данные с текстовых полей. Никаких просчетов физики 3д моделей и подобного нет. Т.е 2D интерфейс.

Соответственно, при большом количестве элементов из стандартного GUI, количество drowcall`ов увеличится.

Будет ли это большим минусом в производительности, даже если 2D ?
Как быть с нестандартными элементами ?

Comment: Все не стандартные элементы можно делать с помощью стандартных компонентов, NGUI жее очень хорошо помогает уже с готовыми функциями и обработчиками, без него придется писать вручную всю логику работы. А GUI очень тяжел для мобильных платформ по этому лучше делать или свой интерфейс с три д кнопками или юзать NGUI для 2Д отображения изображений, тем более он очень хорошо оптимизирует под разные экраны то что сами вы замучаетесь делать вручную.

Answer (score 2):

1. Создаешь канвас
2. Настраиваешь канвас на нужный лад  и прикрепляешь до твоей main camera. Тебе по ходу нужен камера оверлей или что-то в этом духе. Не помню уже.
3. Размещаешь на канвасе нужные обьекты
4. Отключать или включать нужные панели на канвасе для переключения между менюхами.

GUI очень медленный на фоне NGUI. Советую им не пользоватся окроме как для тестовых целей и в небольшом количестве. (например выдать количество фпс)